# Controlling mouse scroll with keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel, xkb

Using xkb I've managed to control mouse buttons with the keyboard. I simply added these lines

```
key <BAR> { [ Pointer_Button1 ] };
key <LEFT> { [ Pointer_Button2 ] };
key <RGHT> { [ Pointer_Button3 ] };
```

to my xkb symbol file, and activated mouse keys here:

Settings > Universal Access > Pointing and Clicking > Mouse Keys

What I now want to do is to control scroll up / scroll down with two other buttons. From what I've read, scroll up / down seems to correspond to button 4 and 5, but adding `Pointer_Button4` and `Pointer_Button5` in my xkb conf doesn't work.

Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I found this in xkb (from 'xkbcomp $DISPLAY temp.xkb')...

```
key <I185> {         [    XF86ScrollUp ] };
key <I186> {         [  XF86ScrollDown ] };
```

Maybe XF86ScrollUp/Down is what you need?